# json.dumps() throwing unicode decode error on mixed encoding dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode

I've got a dict that I'm trying to `json.dumps()` but I'm continually getting

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 7: unexpected end of dat
```

Here's the offending section of the `print`ed dict

```
'secalert': [{'Section': '.reloc\x00\xc9',
```

According the docs, it's my understanding that these non-printables would be converted and escaped as ASCII.

Comment: It means that not all bytestrings in your input are decodable as UTF-8. You'll need to fix that.

Comment: Without any more information as to what part of your input is *not* UTF8, there isn't anything else I can say about this; Igor's proposed dupe is as much use as anything without more detail.

Comment: The issue is that a string contains non-printables. My understanding of json.dumps is that ```If ensure_ascii is True (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the result is a str instance consisting of ASCII characters only.```  The offending section (as ```print```ed) looks like ```'secalert': [{'Section': '.reloc\x00\xc9', ...```

Comment: You are confusing input with output. `\x00\xc9` cannot be decoded as UTF-8.

Comment: `\x00` is a NULL, I'm not aware of any codec that uses that as anything sensible. The `\xc9` after it is not valid UTF8. You'll have to remove those first; perhaps by decoding those values with `.decode('utf8', errors='ignore')`; you'll still have a null codepoint but it'll be a Unicode null codepoint.

Comment: I take it there's no easy way to just represent those characters in ascii automatically (eg: literal ```\xc9``` becomes ascii string ```0xc9```)

Comment: `errors='replace'` will replace them with the [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://codepoints.net/U+fffd) codepoint. But otherwise, you cannot easily, without custom code, replace those bytes with literal ASCII characters and not the rest of your strings.

Comment: Perhaps figuring out why you have those garbage bytes in there in the first place is a more productive approach to the problem.